# Página web multilenguaje PHP. Al cambiar de idioma me regresa a la página de Inicio

Tags: php, html

muy buenas. Soy nuevo en el uso de PHP.
Me propuse hacer una página web básica e intentar hacer que se pueda navegar por ella en español y en inglés.
El caso es que conseguí hacerlo, pero si estoy viendo en español y en la subpágina "about us.php" y le cambio al inglés, se traduce pero me redirecciona al index.php.

Quiero que cuando estoy en una subpágina y le cambio de idioma, se traduzca pero que se quede en el mismo sitio, no que se traduzca y se regrese a la página de inicio. No sé si me explico bien :P Ayudenme por favor. Gracias.

Este es el código del archivo index.php:

```html
<?php
    include "config.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Mi página Web. <?php echo $lang['btn1'] ?></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="index.php"> <?php echo $lang['btn1'] ?> </a></li>
                                
                    <li><a href="about_us.php" > <?php echo $lang['btn2'] ?> </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>            

            <div>
                <p> <?php echo $lang['btn1'] ?> </p>
            </div>            
        </div>
        
        <footer>
            <p><a href="index.php?lang=es"> Español </a> 
            | <a href="index.php?lang=en"> English </a></p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

El código de about_us.php es igual al de index.php pero cambiando "$lang['btn1']" por "$lang['btn2']" en las líneas 8 y 23.

Este es el código del archivo config.php:

```html
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
        {
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "es";
        }

    else if (isset($_GET['lang']))
    {
        if ($_GET['lang'] == "es")
            {
                $_SESSION['lang'] = "es";
            }

        else if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
            {
                $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";  
            }
    }

    require_once "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
?>
```

Los php de los idiomas están en una carpeta llamada "languages". Estas son los llaves para el idioma español, es.php:

```html
<?php
    $lang = array(
        "btn1" => "Inicio",
        "btn2" => "Sobre nosotros",
    );
?>
```

Y estas las del idioma inglés, en.php:

```html
<?php
    $lang = array(
        "btn1" => "Home",
        "btn2" => "About us",
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que bastará con que cambies los **href** para que 'apunten' al lugar que deseas, en este caso el about. También fijate que tienes un espacio en el nombre del archivo, te recomiendo quitarlo.

```
<a href="about.php?lang=es"> Español </a> 
<a href="about.php?lang=en"> English </a>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero no funciona. Al traducirlo quiero que se quede en la misma página, ya sea el index o el about. Este es un ejemplo resumido de lo que intento hacer. El real tiene 7 subpáginas y cambiar el href para que me lleve al "about.php?lang=.." no funcionará en el ejemplo real.

Comment: entonces almacena la session en el servidor para que tengas el idioma desde alli

Comment: Claro!!! ahora acabo de ver la respuesta...y sí, tiene que ver en gran parte con lo que me has dicho. Hay que cambiar el href pero no en el index.php, sino en el about.php....muchisimas gracias.